# returning a list of data to viewModel using Repository pattern from different data sources (network and room)

Tags: android, kotlin, repository, android-room, viewmodel

I'm developing a Kotlin app using MVVM with repository pattern.

I have a main fragment that displays list of asteroids.

Here is the flow I want to achieve.

- When user opens main fragment , I will check if there's asteroids data stored in the local database (room).
- If yes I will displays the stored data
- If no I will call API to get the asteroids then I will store the data from API to local database

So based on my understating of the repository pattern the viewModel should not be concerned about the data source wether it's from API or local database.

So I defined this function in repository that the viewModel will call

```
override suspend fun getAsteroid(): List<Asteroid> {
    var result : List<Asteroid>
    try {
        var isDataAvailable = getAnyAsteroidFromDb()
         if (isDataAvailable == null) {
             result = getAsteroidApi().asDomainModel()
         } else {
             result = getAsteroidFromDb()
         }
    } catch (e : Exception) {

    }
    return result
}
```

`getAnyAsteroidFromDb` checks the data availability in room

`getAsteroidApi` gets the data from netwrok call

`getAsteroidFromDb` gets the data from room

The problem is `getAsteroidFromDb` returns Livedata from Dao

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM asteroid_tbl")
    fun getAsteroidsFromDb () : LiveData<List<AsteroidEntity>>
```

And the function itself `getAsteroid` returns List of Asteroids.

Let's say I changed the return type to Livedata , This will cause another problem because the api doesn't return a Livedata.

I'm kind of stuck here and I think I'm doing something wrong or maybe my understating of the MVVM and repertory pattern still not good enough.

Any thoughts or idea will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more than one solutions to this, but since you are using the MVVM pattern. So I would like to suggest you a pattern for such situations.

Whenever there is a situation where have to check our Local DB or call our backend API. The usual structure of calling is to have one point of data source only to avoid ambiguity and such issues.

So while you can easily get the `value` from LiveData or convert the API response to `LiveData`. I would suggest your structure to be as follows.

- Check Local DB for data.
- If data is there in Local DB, fetch it.
- If data is not there in Local DB, call the API, fetch the results, store it in Local DB.
- On success of API result, you can then query the local DB again and get results.

This ensures your single source of truth remains your DB and you can easily make calls.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to return the LiveData value:

```
override suspend fun getAsteroid(): List<Asteroid> {
var result : List<Asteroid>
try {
    var isDataAvailable = getAnyAsteroidFromDb()
     if (isDataAvailable == null) {
         result = getAsteroidApi().asDomainModel()
     } else {
         result = getAsteroidFromDb().value  //<==List<Asteroid>
     }
} catch (e : Exception) {

}
return result
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to return Livedata from the repository, you can unwrap the Livedata you get from Room and use the value from it. That should give you the list of Asteroids object. So, use something like this:

```
override suspend fun getAsteroid(): List<Asteroid> {
    var result : List<Asteroid>
    try {
        var isDataAvailable = getAnyAsteroidFromDb()
         if (isDataAvailable == null) {
             result = getAsteroidApi().asDomainModel()
         } else {
             val data = getAsteroidFromDb()
             result = data.value
         }
    } catch (e : Exception) {

    }
    return result
}
```